# Using DELETE Rest api to remove array object from Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using Node.js, express, mongodb, and mongoose. I have two files: favorite and favorite-route.

"favorites" in the schema has multiple objects in it array. Given the mongodb assigned _id, I would like to create a delete method to gremove the specified object in the array.

Here is my schema in favorite:

```
    userID:{
        //type: String,
        
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "user",
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    favorites:[{
        
        publication: {
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Pet"
        },

        id: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        comment: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]   
})
```

```
favoritesSchema.statics.deleteFavorite = async (favID)=>{
    return await Favorite.findOneAndUpdate({favID})
}
```

This is my delete method in favorite-route file:

```
router.delete('/:favID', async (req,res)=>{

    let doc = await Favorite.deleteFavorite(req.params.favID)

    if(doc){
        doc.splice(req.params.favID);
        res.send(doc)
        return;
    }

    res.status(404).send({error: "no se encontró esa publicación"})
})
```

And lastly, here is my http:

```
DELETE {{host}}/api/favorites/626eddd14762eb4ae4c77f9e
```

When i test this, it gives me the error:
`TypeError: doc.splice is not a function`

I'd appreciate any tips and insight. I have spent a while searching for answers but most suggested using $pull, which I am unsure how to implement in the delete method.

Thank you :)

Comment: The problem is that you should be passing also the parent object `id` as a parameter to the route to `findById` it and the remove the specified element in the `favorites` array

Answer (score 0):

you should do.

```js
    Favorite.updateOne(
      { userID: user._id }, // this is the query to find the desired favourite list
      { $pull: { favorites: { id : req.params.favID }} }, // this removes  
     
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Where do I need to include that in my existing code? I am assuming in my DELETE method?

Comment: here favoritesSchema.statics.deleteFavorite = async (favID)=>{

Comment: unfortunately req.params.favid isnt defined in that file.

Comment: pass it as an argument  in the delete method 

and in model n, replace req.params.favID with favID